# What is the difference between Keras model.evaluate() and model.predict()?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation

I used Keras biomedical image segmentation to segment brain neurons. I used `model.evaluate()` it gave me Dice coefficient: 0.916. However, when I used `model.predict()`, then loop through the predicted images by calculating the Dice coefficient, the Dice coefficient is 0.82. Why are these two values different?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that every metric in `Keras` is evaluated in a following manner:

1. For each `batch` a metric value is evaluated.
2. A current value of loss (after `k` batches is equal to a mean value of your metric across computed `k` batches).
3. The final result is obtained as a mean of all losses computed for all batches.

Most of the most popular metrics (like `mse`, `categorical_crossentropy`, `mae`) etc. - as a mean of loss value of each example - have a property that such evaluation ends up with a proper result. But in case of Dice Coefficient - a mean of its value across all of the batches is not equal to actual value computed on a whole dataset and as `model.evaluate()` uses such way of computations - this is the direct cause of your problem.

Answer (score 70):

The `model.evaluate` function predicts the output for the given input and then computes the metrics function specified in the `model.compile` and based on `y_true` and `y_pred` and returns the computed metric value as the output.

The `model.predict` just returns back the `y_pred`

So if you use `model.predict` and then compute the metrics yourself, the computed metric value should turn out to be the same as `model.evaluate`

For example, one would use `model.predict` instead of `model.evaluate` in evaluating an RNN/ LSTM based models where the output needs to be fed as input in next time step

Answer (score 21):

The `keras.evaluate()` function will give you the loss value for every batch. The `keras.predict()` function will give you the actual predictions for all samples in a batch, for all batches. So even if you use the same data, the differences will be there because the value of a loss function will be almost always different than the predicted values. These are two different things.

Comment: To be precise, keras.evaluate is not a reliable way of measuring how accurately classifier is going to work in actual world. People should have their own code to calculate this.

Comment: But then again `model.evaluate()` *not only* gives the loss, but also the specified accuracy metrics as defined in `model.compile`, like @javac pointed out. `model.metrics_name` shows what `evaluate()` outputs

Answer (score 13):

It is about regularization. `model.predict()` returns the final output of the model, i.e. answer. While `model.evaluate()` returns the **loss**. The loss is used to train the model (via backpropagation) and it is not the answer.

This [video of ML Tokyo](https://youtu.be/ZJRPTBVBV5c?t=1407) should help to understand the difference between `model.evaluate()` and `model.predict()`.