# Why does the result from evaluate() differ from last epoch result?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a very simple neural-network which works in 250 epochs and in the last epoch it shows the `mae = 0.1397` , however, if i try to get the `model.evaluate((m * test_x + b), predict_y))` then the mae is about `44009.296875`.

**Why there is such big difference ?**

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_x = np.arange(2000)
m = 5
b = 4

train_y = m * train_x + b

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Create a Sequential Nerual Network
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(1,), name="input_layer"))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation=None, name="output_layer"))

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Compile the model
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              metrics=["mae"])

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Train the model
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=250)

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Test the model

test_x = np.arange(2000, 2400)
predict_y = model.predict([test_x])
# ------------------------------------------------------
# Evaluation
print("Evaluate Testing : ", model.evaluate((m * test_x + b), predict_y))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure if you are using the `model.evaluate` method correctly. Similar to the `model.fit` method, when evaluating your model you should provide `x` and `y` values. I get quite similar results when running this code snippet:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_x = np.arange(2000)
m = 5
b = 4
train_y = m * train_x + b

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Create a Sequential Nerual Network
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(1,), name="input_layer"))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation=None, name="output_layer"))

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Compile the model
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              metrics=["mae"])

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Train the model
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=5, batch_size=32)

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Test the model
test_x = np.arange(2000)
predict_y = model.predict([test_x])
# ------------------------------------------------------
# Evaluation
print("Evaluate Testing : ", model.evaluate(test_x,  m * test_x + b, batch_size=32))
```

```
Epoch 1/5
63/63 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 4978.4922 - mae: 4978.4922
Epoch 2/5
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 4954.3252 - mae: 4954.3252
Epoch 3/5
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 4929.9980 - mae: 4929.9980
Epoch 4/5
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 4905.5146 - mae: 4905.5146
Epoch 5/5
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 4880.8120 - mae: 4880.8120
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 4868.2192 - mae: 4868.2192
Evaluate Testing :  [4868.21923828125, 4868.21923828125]
```

Due to the stochastic nature of the whole process, the results will naturally vary a little.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but why should the `evaluate()` method needs `x` and `y`, instead of `tobserved_y` and the `predicted_y` ?

Comment: Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476706/what-is-the-difference-between-keras-model-evaluate-and-model-predict): "The model.evaluate function predicts the output for the given input and then computes the metrics function specified in the model.compile and based on y_true and y_pred and returns the computed metric value as the output [...] "

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate results manually:

```
np.sqrt(np.mean((m * test_x + b) - predict_y)) # manually computing mae

>>> 0.35962627085281185
```

It doesn't make any sense why is that such a big difference here. At least we can assume, that your predictions are not so bad.

There is similar issue in github:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6977.
And kind of official answer here:
https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#why-is-my-training-loss-much-higher-than-my-testing-loss

> **Why is my training loss much higher than my testing loss?**
>
> > A Keras model has two modes: training and testing. Regularization mechanisms, such as Dropout and L1/L2 weight regularization, are turned off at testing time. They are reflected in the training time loss but not in the test time loss.
>
> > Besides, the training loss that Keras displays is the average of the losses for each batch of training data, over the current epoch. Because your model is changing over time, the loss over the first batches of an epoch is generally higher than over the last batches. This can bring the epoch-wise average down. On the other hand, the testing loss for an epoch is computed using the model as it is at the end of the epoch, resulting in a lower loss.